# Does jQuery always safely run functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use jQuery, I always wonder if a particular function is safe to run. For example:

```
$('#myButton').removeClass('hello'); // will this break if the 'hello' class isn't present?

$('#myButton').addClass('hello'); // will this duplicate the 'hello' class if it already exists on the button?

$('#myButton').text('newText'); // will this run to completion if the text on the element already says 'newText'
```

These are some examples, but my overarching question relates to whether jQuery has some philosophy behind the safety of its functions. Is it safe to assume that we as developers should institute safety checks, or can we assume that jQuery's functions have built in safety checks?

Also, I'm particularly curious about the last of the three examples above. Does it run like this:

```
if ($myButton.text() !== 'newText') {
    $myButton.text('newText');
}
```

or simply like this:

```
$myButton.text('newText');
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, jquery generally does not throw errors, even if the element/class/text/etc you are referencing is not present, and no, `addClass` does not duplicate classes.  It mostly 'just works'

Comment: You can test these quite easily yourself, but to answer your questions, no it won't break, no, yes it will run to completion, jQuery does have built in null/empty checks when running methods on jQuery objects, and the second example is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, JQuery goes out of its way to not break when you pass it a missing selector. As to the other question, take a look at the code:

```
this.empty().each( function() {
    if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
        this.textContent = value;
    }
} );
```

It looks like it actually runs .empty() to clean up the element and then injects the content, regardless of if it's the same content.